# How do I collect the three plants in level 13 “Bump”?

Tags: spirits

I 'need' to save eleven spirits and to collect the three plants in order to perfectly complete the level 13, called "Bump". How can I collect these plants surrounded by spines? And how can I do it without making more than two spirits vanish?

[image: Level 13 "Bump"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click a flying spirit, it will fall down and any flower below will be activated.